# Iterating over enums TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, enums

I'm trying to iterate over this enum.
However I'm facing issues with extracting values from the enum.
I can extract the value if i give it a hardcoded string like this.

```
export enum Values {
  ACE = 'A',
  TWO = '2',
  THREE = '3',
  FOUR = '4',
  FIVE = '5',
  SIX = '6',
  SEVEN = '7',
  EIGHT = '8',
  NINE = '9',
  TEN = '10',
  JACK = 'J',
  QUEEN = 'Q',
  KING = 'K',
}

console.log(Values['TWO']);
```

But as soon as i give it the multiple string values from the enum like below.

```
export enum Values {
  ACE = 'A',
  TWO = '2',
  THREE = '3',
  FOUR = '4',
  FIVE = '5',
  SIX = '6',
  SEVEN = '7',
  EIGHT = '8',
  NINE = '9',
  TEN = '10',
  JACK = 'J',
  QUEEN = 'Q',
  KING = 'K',
}

for (let value in Values) {
  console.log(Values[value]);
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof Values'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof Values'.

25   console.log(Values[value]);
```

Completely new to TypeScript so might be missing something.

Cheers to anyone who could give me some guidance.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-star-hlg2f?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of the loop variable while iterating using `for-in` loop over `enum Values` is implicitly `any`, so you get the compile error.

```
for (let value in Values) {
  console.log(Values[value]);
}
```

The variable `value` is of type `any`, which cannot be used to index the `enum Values`.

Open issue in TypeScript [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500).

If you want to iterate over the key-value pairs of the `enum` you can do so with the help of `Object.entries`:

```
enum Values {
  ACE = 'A',
  TWO = '2',
  THREE = '3',
  FOUR = '4',
  FIVE = '5',
  SIX = '6',
  SEVEN = '7',
  EIGHT = '8',
  NINE = '9',
  TEN = '10',
  JACK = 'J',
  QUEEN = 'Q',
  KING = 'K',
}

//Both key and value
Object.entries(Values).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value)
});

//keys
Object.keys(Values).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key);
});

//values
Object.values(Values).forEach(value => {
    console.log(value);
});
```